# Unable to debug cryptic error messages because of AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I use Visual Studio & asp.net. One of the reasons I detest using AJAX even for little things is that I often get Javascript errors that are virtually impossible to debug. For instance, an error occurs in my code behind file which is a server error but my browser says a javascript error occurred on line 4,000 in MicrosoftAjax.js.

Is there a setting or someway I can make visual studio or the browser indicate the server side location/line# of the error?

Comment: I answered my own question. Just had to turn the debugger on. Did not have to set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the actual line where the error occurred by running the project in debug mode. Did not have to set a breakpoint. The debugger kicked in and flagged the error where it occurred on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- Check the Network Tab and check what is getting called on the back-end
- Check the response header / content from the AJAX request
- Put a break point in Visual Studio to check what is happening server-side
- Put a break point in the Browser to check what is happening client-side

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is also very useful in this type of situation - you can use it to trace exactly what's going on.